# When to use built in ASP.NET login control

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

might be a dumb question but since i am so new with ASP.NET i have a hard time understanding when you should use for example the built in login controller, vs. a custom login-form with custom code-behind?

Coming from PHP and this is why i cant seem to get a grip on this, same about the ASP.NET SiteMapPath with a menu controller vs. just using a href or asp:HyperLink?

Answer (score 0):

If the login control suits your needs, use it, after all it's tested, secure, standardised (so hopefully easily maintained). If you don't have any exotic requirements go with it. It's pretty flexible.

On a tangent, if you're new to asp.net but not tied to it, I'd highly recommend MVC instead.